# WPF and creating a "endless" canvas

Tags: .net, wpf, canvas

I am trying to make a small drawing program for small children. I am thinking on making a `canvas`, and allowing them to draw on it. But I do not want to specify a size, I want to zoom out and thus allow a "endless" piece of paper (using pan + zoom to navigate). but how do I do this, the `canvas` seems to have only a fixed size, and resizing it doesn't seem to work, How about the zoom, my drawings doesn't seem to be vector based, they are very "jagged" when zooming close.

Any other control that would be better?

Comment: It's a nice idea - just wondering a little bit about the combination of "for small children" and "pan and zoom navigation."  Although my young'uns like to play on the computer, I'm not sure that they would be ready for something that complex unless it was made really simple.

Comment: My thoughts are: "touch screen" and a clever way to pan/zoom without drawing,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [InkCanvas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.inkcanvas.aspx) control, it gives you an area like a board where you may draw or handwrite; apart from this it provides various other features out of the box. You can easily find a sample for implementing zooming in InkCanvas. Some helpful links -

Draw using the InkCanvas:
http://www.kirupa.com/blend_wpf/inkcanvas_pg1.htm

Seres of articles on using InkCanvas-
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/swick/archive/tags/fun+with+ink+_2600_amp_3b00_+xaml/