# How to achieve a "infinite-sized" canvas effect in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

My Goal is to create a Canvas where you can translate the child elements to where you want just by moving around the whole canvas (like for example in the grasshopper plugin from rhino). I tried with "translateTransform" but then the problem arises that the height or width of the canvas isn't big enough to include the whole window again. I tried to solve this problem with adding Width and Height to the Canvas whenever it gets dragged around, but the Size of the Canvas just doesn't seem to change.

Here is my window.xaml:

```
<Window x:Name="Window" x:Class="Oolong.Windows.Project.ProjectPlan"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Oolong.Windows.Project"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Projektplan" Height="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeightKey}}" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidthKey}}" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" ShowInTaskbar="False" Icon="/Oolong;component/Resources/Images/icon2.png">
    <Window.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Oolong;component/Resources/Images/ui/canvas_bg.png" TileMode="FlipY"      Stretch="Uniform" AlignmentY="Top"  Viewport="0,0,150,50" ViewportUnits="Absolute" />
    </Window.Background>
    <Canvas x:Name="Grid" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_OnMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseDown="Grid_MouseDown" MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove" MouseUp="Grid_MouseUp" MouseWheel="Grid_OnMouseWheel" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenWidthKey}}" Height="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.MaximizedPrimaryScreenHeightKey}}">
        <Rectangle x:Name="NewTaskRectangle" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="87" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="208" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <Label x:Name="NewTaskLabel" Content="Gib den Namen der Aufgabe ein..." HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,17,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Visibility="Hidden"/>
            <TextBox  x:Name="NewTaskTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="10,48,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="189" Visibility="Hidden" KeyUp="NewTaskTextBox_OnKeyUp"/>
            <Border x:Name="NewTaskTemplate" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2.5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="30" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="#FFE2C027" Padding="5" Focusable="True" CornerRadius="6" Width="15" Visibility="Hidden" MinWidth="150" MinHeight="30" MouseRightButtonUp="NewTaskTemplate_OnMouseRightButtonUp">
                <Border.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu x:Name="NewTaskContextMenu">
                        <MenuItem x:Name="AddIssueMenuItem" Header="Arbeitsschritt hinzufügen" Click="AddIssueMenuItem_OnClick"/>
                        <MenuItem x:Name="DeleteMenuItem" Header="Löschen" Click="DeleteMenuItem_OnClick"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Border.ContextMenu>
            </Border>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="ScaleTransform"/>
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="Tt" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

And Here the relevant C# Code:

```
 private void NewTaskTemplate_OnMouseRightButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = e.GetPosition(Grid);
        bool hasClickedOnTask = false;
        if (App.ProjectPlan.Tasks != null)
        {
            var tasks = App.ProjectPlan.Tasks.DistinctBy(task => task.Position);
            var selectedTasks =
                tasks.Where(
                (task =>
                    Math.Abs(task.Position.X - position.X + 10) < task.Title.Length*13 &&
                    Math.Abs(task.Position.Y - position.Y) < 20));
            IEnumerable<Task> enumerable = selectedTasks as Task[] ?? selectedTasks.ToArray();
            if (enumerable.Any())
            {
                _selectedTask = enumerable.Last();
                hasClickedOnTask = true;
            }
        }
        if (!hasClickedOnTask) return;
        NewTaskContextMenu.IsOpen = true;
        e.Handled = true;
        SetGridSize();
    }

    Point _mStart;
    Vector _mStartOffset;

    private void SetGridSize()
    {
        Grid.Width += 250;
        Grid.Height += 250;
        Grid.UpdateLayout();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.Cursor = Cursors.ScrollAll;
        _mStart = e.GetPosition(Window);
        _mStartOffset = new Vector(Tt.X, Tt.Y);
        Grid.CaptureMouse();
    }

    private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Grid.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            Vector offset = Point.Subtract(e.GetPosition(Window), _mStart);

            Tt.X = _mStartOffset.X + offset.X;
            Tt.Y = _mStartOffset.Y + offset.Y;
            SetGridSize();
        }
    }

    private void Grid_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Grid.ReleaseMouseCapture();
        Grid.Cursor = Cursors.Arrow;
    }

    private void Grid_OnMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        Point position = e.GetPosition(Window);
        ScaleTransform.CenterX = position.X;
        ScaleTransform.CenterY = position.Y;
        _gridZoom = _gridZoom + e.Delta / 2400.00;
        ScaleTransform.ScaleX = _gridZoom;
        ScaleTransform.ScaleY = _gridZoom;
        if (e.Delta > 0)
        {
            SetGridSize();
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

The Canvas was at the beginning a grid but that didn't work either. It works to move around the canvas including all elements of course, but if you put it out of the window, you cant move anything anymore because the canvas isn't there anymore. How Can I workaorund this problem, so that the user gets the impression that the canvas is infinite?

Comment: I tried to add a Grid Container around the original Grid and fire the events on the container, but only transform the inner grid, but unfortunately that doesnt solve the problem, and I dont know why...

Comment: So you have a visual area that is part of a potentially infinite logical area, you want to place elements on the logical area and you want to drag it around in a way that the edge of the logical area is never dragged into the visual area?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I if I do the answer is yes... The Grid should be draggable infinitely to the right or the left, but when dragged to the bounds of the window, and then doing a right click in the middle shows me that the grid just has moved completely to the left or right and can not be translated at this mouse position

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF and creating a "endless" canvas](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488608/wpf-and-creating-a-endless-canvas)

Comment: I just found out that there exists an **InkCanvas** which could probably solve my problems.. thank you for your interest anyway...

Comment: Good to hear, not like I had any kind of working solution available, so if the InkCanvas solves your problem, then thats perfect.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should surround your `Grid` with `ScrollView` and edit `Width` and `Height` properties after each dropping the dragged element outside `Grid'. Something like this:

```
private void UIElement_OnPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canmove) //field is used to define whether element dragged or not
        {
            var c = (Control) sender;
            c.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, e.GetPosition(Canvas).X - p.X);
            c.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, e.GetPosition(Canvas).Y - p.Y);

            var leftprop = Convert.ToDouble(c.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty));
            if (leftprop > Canvas.Width)
                Canvas.Width = leftprop + c.Width+10;
           
        }
    }
```

Comment: this way the events like mousebuttondown can't be fired anymore

Comment: @hardking and, as I understand, you can not do without this events?

Comment: exactly I need those events because I want to create a popup for example when someone clicks on the canvas

Comment: @hardking and what's stopping you to use PreviewEvents for this purpose?